# Computer crashes and shows HDMI no signal, must be unplugged to restart

Tags: crash, crash-reports, hdmi

When playing certain games or viewing certain websites, my computer will suddenly crash and my monitor will display "HDMI no signal" the computer cannot be restarted without unplugging it from the wall. Upon viewing the crash report I see event 10016 related to permissions I think, but I'm a moron. Any and all solutions are greatly appreciated. Relevant components are as follows:

Graphics Card: RTX 2080
Power supply: EVGA supernova 1000g2
Storage: Sandisk 500Gb
CPU: Ryzen 2700X
Monitor: Both HP EliteDisplay E222 and another HP monitor

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not supplying your q with the crash report, I can only suspect your problem is rooted to either one of these:

1. Bug in the accompanying display driver and/or directX installation
   Proposed solution : try and obtain the latest version of your RTX 2080, do a 2D and 3D test run afterwards to ensure everythings proper
2. Fan or cooling related issue. Some games might force your hardwares to work harder, especially over continuous use. Check your fan and coolings to ensure they are moving and cooling as fast as they should. Also install a temp monitoring software if you need to be extra sure.

Hope those help m8